# Strange behavior of time.Since()

Tags: go, pprof

I am running a GO (1.9.2) program and I have code similar to:

```
startTime := time.Now()
...
...
fmt.Printf("%v (1) %v \n", user.uid, int64(time.Since(startTime)))
fmt.Printf("%v (F) %v \n", user.uid, int64(time.Since(startTime)))
```

(The two fmt statements are on consecutive lines)

I expected that the printout would be of similar time but here are some results of the print:

```
921 (1)    2000100
921 (F) 3040173800
```

(3 seconds)

```
360 (1)    2000100
360 (F) 1063060800
```

(1 second)

```
447 (1)    4000200
447 (F) 2564146700
```

(2.5 seconds)

The time difference is consistently high between the two printouts.

**What could be the explanation of this phenomenon?**

Extra info:
According to pprof there are ~15000 goroutines running at the time of the prints but most of them are waiting for incoming data on sockets.

I ran the code with `GODEBUG=gctrace=1` but there aren't many GC printouts, not nearly as many as the number of printouts of my code.

**EDIT:**
It seems that storing the result of time.Since() into variables as suggested by @Verran solves the issue.

Changing to `fmt` to `log` didn't help but the prints are no longer synchronized.

It appears the "problem" is in the way `fmt` is handled in a high load environment. I hope someone could shed some light to what is going on here.

Comment: 1. Three seconds elapsed between the two time.Since calls, 2. Monotonic time.

Comment: It might not be related, but it would be better to use a synchronized method of output to make sure you're not interleaving writes to stdout. Plus, if you use `log` you can also get absolute timestamps to further corroborate your findings.

Comment: Note that printing to console (or file) involves a syscall, which often results in the goroutine in question being rescheduled.  If you have a ton of goroutines running, it might be a bit before this goroutine is scheduled again and can proceed to the second print statement.

Comment: What does it look like if you write the two Durations to variables and then print them out together in one `fmt.Printf("%v\n%v\n", since1, since2)` statement?

Comment: @Verran If fixes the problem if I do that. The numbers match.

Comment: I'd say that pretty much confirms in my mind that it's context switching on the fmt.Println and not getting back to the next time.Since() call for a while because there are so many other goroutines waiting for a chance to run.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think the problem is related to your posted code. To find the problem I suggest printing [mem stats](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#ReadMemStats) like number of GC calls and how much was spent in GC between two prints. I suggest to print `startTime` too to be 100% sure that two consecutive print belongs to same goroutine.

Comment: Each user runs its own goroutine so as long as the ids match its the same one. I thought that if I set gctrace to 1 I will see all GC actions.